# Angular 9: Why is my custom EventEmitter not working?

Tags: angular, typescript, events, decorator, eventemitter

I've been trying out Angular 9 and have been stuck on the correct use of the `@Output()`-decorator and the `EventEmitter`-class for a while now. For some reason, my event does not seem to be bubbled up to my child component's immediate parent component. My child component is called `NavbarComponent` and is supposed to fire the `toggletool`-event on a button click. The relevant parts of the `navbar.component.ts`-file look like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.scss']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output('toggletool') toggleEvent: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  ...

  toggle(id: string) {
    this.toggleEvent.emit(id);
  }

}
```

The `toggle(...)`-function is definitely called and the `id` parameter is set correctly. I'm now trying to catch the event in my `AppComponent`. The template looks like this:

```
<app-location-tool [isActive]="toolIsActive('locationtool')" (toggletool)="toggleTool($event)">
</app-location-tool>
```

The `app.component.ts`-file declares a function `toggleTool(...)` that looks like this:

```
toggleTool(event) {
  console.log(event);
}
```

However, this function is never called (judging by the missing console output), and I don't really know why. I'm guessing I have overlooked some minor mistake and am hoping that you guys can help me out.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your component's selector is `app-navbar`, but you have used `app-location-tool`